# Как сделать многофункциональную кнопку по типу play\pause?

Tags: c#, wpf, button

Кнопка в WPF обычно связывается с командой и все решает команда.
В моем случае, хочется кнопку `start \ pause \ continue`.

Ни разу не сталкивался с такими кнопками, так что кроме трех отдельных команд и их смене при выполнении не смог ничего придумать. Есть готовые решения на эту тему?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37383/discussion-on-question-by-monk-------pl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tl;dr - все решения своеобразные получились, сам выбрал вариант "Одна кнопка с пачкой команд", так проще прикручивать к остальному коду.**

Я добавляю командам свойство Name для отображения на форме, но не расписываю это в коде ниже. Все собранные примеры более-менее одинаково по сложности позволяют пробросить текст на форму.

### Отдельные кнопки с отдельными командами

> А почему бы не завести три кнопки, и включать/убирать видимость в
>   зависимости от текущего состояния VM?

Как в итоге выглядит реализация:
В модели страницы объявляем нужные команды

```
  this.UpdateWithPause = new UpdateCommand();
  this.Pause = new PauseCommand();
  this.Continue = new ContinueCommand();
```

На странице - батоны друг поверх друга:

```
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
        Command="{Binding UpdateWithPause}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
        Command="{Binding Pause}"/>
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
        Command="{Binding Continue}"/>
```

Плюс рулим видимостью у батонов:

```
    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter={StaticResource B2V}}"/>
```

Главная особенность - синхронно обновлять `CanExecute` у команд, иначе видимость может не отобразить нужную кнопку вовремя.

### Одна кнопка с пачкой команд

> чем плох вариант с тремя командами и их сменой в процессе выполнения?

Т.к. команды принадлежат вьюмодели, а переключать их во вью модели какая то конкретная команда вроде и не должна уметь, то решил упаковать пачку команд в одну, для переключения команд в одной точке.
Вышло визуально намного сложнее предыдущего варианта:

```
  public class UpdateWithPauseCommand : BaseCommand
  {
    private BaseCommand Update;
    private BaseCommand Pause;
    private BaseCommand Continue;
    private BaseCommand activeCommand;

    private BaseCommand ActiveCommand
    {
      get { return activeCommand; }
      set
      {
        activeCommand = value;
        OnCanExecuteChanged();
      }
    }

    public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
      return ActiveCommand.CanExecute(parameter);
    }

    public override void Execute(object parameter)
    {
      if (ActiveCommand == Update)
      {
        ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
        ActiveCommand = Pause;
      }
      else if (ActiveCommand == Pause)
      {
        ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
        ActiveCommand = Continue;
      }
      else if (ActiveCommand == Continue)
      {
        ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
        ActiveCommand = Pause;
      }
    }

    public UpdateWithPauseCommand()
    {
      this.Update = new UpdateCommand();
      this.Pause = new PauseCommand();
      this.Continue = new ContinueCommand();
      this.ActiveCommand = this.Update;
      this.Update.CanExecuteChanged += UpdateOnCanExecuteChanged;
    }

    private void UpdateOnCanExecuteChanged(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
      if (this.Update.CanExecute(sender) && this.ActiveCommand != this.Update)
        this.ActiveCommand = this.Update;
    }

  }
```

Т.к. команда `Start` может завершиться самостоятельно и после этого снова должна быть доступна именно она же, приходится цепляться к событию изменения доступности, не совсем очевидная реализация. Зато - один батон и не надо рулить видимостью батонов. Со стороны вьюмодели это обычная команда. И уж вьюшка вообще не должна задумываться о том, что тут будет какая то неочевидная команда с разными состояниями.

### Одна команда, без вложенных команд

> чем Вас не устраивает принятие решения, что далее выполнять, в
>   команде?

Собственно, просто "разворачиваем" предыдущий вариант, вытаскивая код из команд.

```
public override bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
  return true;
}

public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
  base.Execute(parameter);

  if (CanStart)
  {
    // Start
  }

  else if (!IsPaused)
  {
    // Pause it
  }

  else if (IsPaused)
  {
    // U can continue
  }
}
```

Работать становится тяжелее, если кода очень много, команды всё таки скрывают реализацию и просто предоставляют удобный интерфейс.

### ToggleButton

Батон поддерживает 3 состояния из коробки, визуально правда разница видна только в зажатом. В чем плюс - можно паузу сделать зажатой к примеру, выглядит интересно:

```
    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="1"
                  IsThreeState="True"
                  Command="{Binding UpdateWithPause}"
                  IsChecked="{Binding UpdateWithPause.Toggle}"/>
```

В команду добавляем признак:

```
public bool? Toggle
{
  get { return toggle; }
  set
  {
    toggle = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
  }
}
```

Ну и рулим, хотя бы вручную:

```
public override void Execute(object parameter)
{
  if (ActiveCommand == Update)
  {
    ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
    ActiveCommand = Pause;
    Toggle = null;
  }
  else if (ActiveCommand == Pause)
  {
    ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
    ActiveCommand = Continue;
    Toggle = true;
  }
  else if (ActiveCommand == Continue)
  {
    ActiveCommand.Execute(parameter);
    ActiveCommand = Pause;
    Toggle = null;
  }
}
```

В техническом плане разницы нет, так что прикручивать к батону можно что угодно.

Comment: Проверил и расписал все предложенные варианты. Если вы где-то имели в виду что-то другое - отпишите, что именно не так.

Answer (score 0):

Может `ToggleButton` поможет вам? Можете прочитать [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx) или поищите что нибудь сами.

Comment: Посмотрю, визуально интересно выглядит.

Comment: Посмотрел, решения он готового в любом случае не дает, просто визуальные плюшки.

Answer (score 0):

```
Init state == "pause";

if (Input.GetKey("space") && state == "pause")
{
   Play();
   state == "play";
}
else if(Input.GetKey("space") && ((state == "play") || (state == "continue")))
{
  Pause();
  state == "pause";
}
else(Input.GetKey("space")) //Не понимаю зачем вообще функция **continue**? Почему не **play**?
{
  Continue();
  state == "continue";
}
```

Скорее всего я не правильно понял, но мб поможет. Можете, пожалуйста объяснить более подробней условия.? Как на одной кнопки уместить 3 условия? Может можно сделать подсчёт по количиствам нажатий, например: 2 нажатия подряд кнопки будет ставить на паузу, а одно - плей или континью, зависимо от того, в каком состоянии сейчас находится объект?

Comment: У меня как раз примерно так сейчас выглядит код в обработчике нажатия кнопки, сижу и думаю как отрефакторить. Зависит всё от состояния конечно.

Comment: Я тоже порозмышляю тогда. Главное, что я понял идею... Если решишь вопрос, напиши, пожалуйста, ответ :)

Comment: Расписал ниже отдельным ответом, собственно этот вариант в немного другом виде, но попал.

Comment: Эээ... Я правильно понял `Input.GetKey("space")` — вы предлагаете обработку клавиатуры вручную?

Comment: Как пример написал, хотел выяснить окончательно суть вопроса. Можно и на кнопку подобный скпипт повесить и при нажатии на него, делать эти же действия